# "config.h" used by but not bundled with libxml

Tags: objective-c, c, libxml2

libxml uses the following line of code in libxml.h but it doesn't come bundled with libxml.

```
#include "config.h"
```

I'm trying to use XMPPFramework for Objective-C, in Swift. The XMPPFramework has libxml as a dependency.

Comment: You shouldn't have a libxml.h file, it's only used internally when building libxml2 itself. What are you really doing ?

Comment: I just pulled the library from `git clone git://git.gnome.org/libxml2` and added it to my project.

Comment: That sounds like the very hard way of doing it. Get a prebuilt libxml2. If you insist on building it from source, you're supposed to run the ./autogen.sh file, then  ./configure && make && make install

Comment: You're right, prebuilt is easier, thanks. However, I can't find anything for Mavericks 10.9.

Answer (score 0):

You could try including these:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
```

As found on:

http://wiki.xmlsoft.org/The_libxml2_Library#Installing

Comment: I assume you mean add it to my bridging header in Objective-C?

Comment: Yes, but that is also assuming it is installed as well